# Hide the borders between countries Gmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I hide the borders between countries on Google map. 
this code worked before:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
  center: { lat: 28.9037071, lng: -5.226728},
  zoom: 5
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var stylesArray = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
  {
    featureType: 'administrative.country',
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', stylesArray);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}
```

And last week, it no longer works :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Google Maps itself. It has been confirmed, but has not been fixed yet.

You can keep an eye on [this bug report page](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7165) or click the star icon to be notified when the problem is fixed.

Comment: Exactly, I just found this ticket. 
I can not believe this regression.