# How To remove dash lines in React Native maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-maps

[image: maps screenshot]
I have a problem that I want to remove the dash line that divide Morocco in React Native
that simply my code , I tried Many things and didn't work ,then I remove it .

```
import React from "react";
import {View,StyleSheet,Text} from "react-native";
import {StatusBar} from "expo-status-bar";
import MapView,{PROVIDER_GOOGLE,PROVIDER_DEFAULT} from "react-native-maps";
import {Polygon} from "react-native-maps";

export default function Map({navigation}){

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <MapView style={styles.map}  />
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%'
    },
    map:{
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%'
    }
});
```

I tried Many times to remove that dash line and I failed , if You have any idea please share it

Comment: I havent seen any option to remove dashed lines.. Either it removes all boundaries or it shows all. I would also like to see solution to this.

Comment: have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073984/hide-the-borders-between-countries-gmap

Comment: I don't Means Borders Between Countries ,I Means **The Dash line -----**